# Can multiple elements that share a state have an update only propagate to a single element

Tags: reactjs

Say I have a state:

```
const [isLess, setIsLess] = useState(true);
```

And two elements sharing this state:

```
// some content
<span onPointerDown{changeStateToSeeLess}>
    See All <ExpandIcon/>
</span>

// some content
<span onPointerDown{changeStateToSeeLess}>
    See All <ExpandIcon/>
</span>
```

Can I update the state of only one span when it is clicked?If not how can I update only one span to "See Less" on a click(pointerdown)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [react expand and collapse just one panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48013570/react-expand-and-collapse-just-one-panel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is a boolean.  What you *want* is an array.  (Or object, any structure which can hold *multiple* values.)

For example, consider this state:

```
const [isLess, setIsLess] = useState([true, true]);
```

Now `isLess` contains *two* values (identified only by their position in the array, for demo purposes).  Those *two* values can then be used independently.  For example:

```
<span onPointerDown={() => changeStateToSeeLess(0)}>
  See All <ExpandIcon/>
</span>

<span onPointerDown={() => changeStateToSeeLess(1)}>
  See All <ExpandIcon/>
</span>
```

Here you see that each event handler is providing some identifying value to the change handler.  The handler can then use that identifier to know which array value to update:

```
const changeStateToSeeLess = (id) => {
  setIsLess(isLess.map(x, i) => i == id ? false : x);
};
```

In this case the callback to `map()` is checking if the provided `id` matches the position/index in the array and, if so, sets that value to `false`.  Otherwise it doesn't change the value.

You can expand this in a variety of ways.  For example, instead of relying on the array position to identify the element, you can have an explicit identifier.  And instead of an array of boolean values, you can have an array of objects which contain identifiers and boolean state values.